# Latex cannot find `.sty` files

Tags: packages, installing, texlive, mactex

I am on a mac and I believe I am using MacTeX. I am getting errors of the sort:

```
File `fullpage.sty' not found.
```

When I run `locate fullpage.sty` I get

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/fullpage.sty
```

But when I run `kpsewhich fullpage.sty` I get nothing. I have already tried `sudo texhash` and `sudo mktexlsr` to no avail. I think the problem may be that I have two conflicting TeX Live versions installed—I recently installed QuTIP and I think during the process a basic version was installed via macports—but of this I am not certain. I have no idea how to proceed.

I have two questions: How can I get LaTeX to find `fullpage.sty`? And, if someone can see the real cause of the above error or knows how to find it, how can I remedy the situation?

Comment: There should be a pane in System Preferences to choose your active TeX Distribution. Please check its setting.

Comment: Hi Crissov. Thank you for your reply. In the TeX Distribution pane only one option is shown: TeXLive-2013. Underneath it reads: “Full TeX Live 2013 Distribution.” This option has two suboptions ‘Intel 64’ or ‘Universal’. Unfortunately, selecting neither suboption solved my problem. Plowman.

Comment: You can check what your system thinks it should search with `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFMAIN` (works on Linux, at least).  The command returns this line for me: `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist`

Comment: Hi jon. `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFMAIN` returns `/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive`. It seems this is wrong? Should I get `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist`?

Comment: (If you use @<name> that person gets pinged.) Sounds odd given where your `fullpage.sty` file is.  Have you set your paths correctly?  If I issue `echo $PATH`, one of the items returned is an item that corresponds to the output of `which kpsewhich`.  (Note: I'm only operating on the assumption that Macs mimic *nix setups on this sort of stuff; seems like it does, but someone else should know better the degree of overlap.)

Comment: @jon (Thanks for that tip.) Yes, it is very odd. Everything was working fine until I got QuTIP working. Running `echo $PATH` returns `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin`. And `which kpsewhich` returns `/opt/local/bin/kpsewhich`. Those two seem to agree with each other, but not with my full texlive installation.

Comment: Indeed: your paths don't match the (new?) install.  Does macports install to `/opt`?  Is that (not) the one you want to use?  In Linux, you want to set the path per-user in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`, or in `/etc/environment`, but I'm not sure where you should be doing it on a Mac...

Comment: @jon As I understand it, though I'm no expert, one sets their path on the Mac as in Linux; in `~/.bashrc` or `/.profile`. MacPorts seems to install to `/opt/local/` by default. After comparing `/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive` and `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist` I am convinced that I have a full install in the latter, but a basic install in the former. It would be nice if I could remove texlive as installed by MacPorts, but could this disturb QuTIP? Next best thing, I guess, is to somehow get kpathsea to use my full install. And yet next is to install texlive-full with MacPorts again.

Comment: Well, then, I use this in `~/.profile`: `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`, which, mutatis mutandis, should then work for you; obviously replace `x86_64-linux` with what makes sense on your end.  Then run `source ~/.profile` and try `which kpsewhich`.   (No promises on my part that this won't bork your system, etc.)

Comment: @jon I wrote in `~/.bashrc` the line `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin:$PATH`. And the question is solved. If I discover some borking down the track I'll just bite the bullet and install texlive-full with MacPorts. But all good for now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Old question, but this is a common problem. If you installed via MacTeX, TeX Live will end up in /usr/local/texlive, but I believe MacPorts installs under /opt by default (it did last time I checked, but it's been a few years). Hence, you do indeed have two conflicting TeX distributions, and you're running `kpsewhich` from the MacPorts install. If you enter `which kpsewhich` in Terminal, it probably points to `/opt/local/bin/kpsewhich` or something similar.

The easiest way to fix this is to edit your `PATH` environment variable so that `/usr/texbin` comes first. If you're using `bash`, your `~/.bash_profile`, you would have something like

```
PATH=/usr/texbin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:…:/foo/bar/bin
```

Alternately, if macports sets your `PATH` by sourcing a script in `~/.bash_profile`, as Fink does (or did), you can add a final line to your profile of

```
PATH=/usr/texbin:$PATH
```

A couple of notes:

- this will not affect `PATH` settings for any GUI applications, only programs launched from a shell
- for a TeX Live not installed via MacTeX, you'd use the appropriate full path, e.g., `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin` instead of /usr/texbin

Answer (score 14):

I had this issue, but none of the above solved it. Here is what worked:

### Diagnosing the Issue:

1. I am on OSX 10.9.5 and installed BasicTex 2015 from here http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html
2. I wanted fullpage.sty, but `\usepackage{fullpage}` was not working
3. I checked my path using `echo $PATH`, and `/Library/TeX/texbin` was the only tex related entry, so that wasn't the problem
4. `kpsewhich fullpage.sty` returned nothing, so I knew that latex didn't know where this file was
5. `ls /usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/` returned a list of several packages, but `fullpage/` was not among them, so I then knew it was not included with BasicTex and I just needed to install it

### Installing the Package:

6. New packages are installed with `sudo tlmgr install fullpage`, but this returned the following error:

   ```
     tlmgr: package repository
         http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet tlmgr install:
         package fullpage not present in repository. tlmgr: action install
         returned a warning.
   ```
7. I realized something was amiss, so I looked up the package on CTAN https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fullpage?lang=en and found this very important line:

   > The package is part of the [preprint](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/preprint) bun­dle.

   That was the key clue. I just needed to install the "preprint" package.

## Solution:

8. I installed the "preprint" package via `sudo tlmgr install preprint`. This was successful:

   ```
     tlmgr: package repository
         http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/texlive/tlnet [1/1,
         ??:??/??:??] install: preprint [7k] tlmgr: package log updated:
         /usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log running
         mktexlsr ... done running mktexlsr.
   ```

## Testing:

9. I checked the install with `kpsewhich fullpage.sty`, and this time it returned `/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/fullpage.sty`, which confirmed the solution. I then recompiled my document and it worked.

Boom. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.